# fscanf() function error

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a newbie to c programming. I've written a program using `fscanf()` function:

```
fscanf(fileptr, "%s\n", word);
```

But while I ran the program it was stuck in the terminal. I try to run `GDB` on the program and it show the following lines:

```
109     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
(gdb) 
111         fscanf(fileptr, "%s\n", word);
(gdb) 
__isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x603010, format=0x400cbd "%s\n") at isoc99_fscanf.c:26
26  isoc99_fscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

And then these lines:

```
(gdb) 
_IO_vfscanf_internal (s=s@entry=0x603010, format=0x400cbd "%s\n", argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdd48, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:225
225 vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Is there any problem with the compiler, Or am I missing something? I compiled with:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror hash.c -o hash
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>  

#define MAXLENGTH 10

// structure for each node in hash
typedef struct node
{
    char* word;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

// global pointer for the root node
node* root = NULL;
node* table[26] = {};

// function declearations
int hash_function(char data[MAXLENGTH]);
void load_words(FILE* fileptr);
bool check_word(char* word);

// main function takes command line arguments
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // validates user input at command line
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        printf("Usage : ./hash <word>\n");
        return 1001;
    }

    // loads the dictionary
    FILE* file_ptr = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    if (file_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("failed to load the file!\n");
        return 1002;
    }
    else
    {
        load_words(file_ptr);
    }

    // checks if the word is in dictionary
    if (check_word(argv[1]) == true)
    {
        printf("Word spelled right!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Word spelled wrong!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

// hash function
int hash_function(char data[MAXLENGTH])
{
    if (isalpha(data[0]) != 0)
    {
        int res = tolower(data[0]);
        res = res - 'a';
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not a word!\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

// check_word function
bool check_word(char* word)
{
    int hash = hash_function(word);
    if (hash != -1)
    {
        root = table[hash];

        while(root != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(word, root->word) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// load words into hash table
void load_words(FILE* fileptr)
{
    char word[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fileptr, "%s\n", word);

        int hash = hash_function(word);

        if (hash != -1)
        {
            if (table[hash] == NULL)
            {
                table[hash] = malloc(sizeof(node));
                if (table[hash] == NULL)
                {
                    printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
                    return;
                }

                table[hash]->word = word;
                table[hash]->next = NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                root = table[hash];

                while (root->next != NULL)
                    root = root->next;

                node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
                if (newNode == NULL)
                {
                    printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
                    return;
                }

                newNode->word = word;
                newNode->next = NULL;

                root->next = newNode;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            printf("hash failed!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've install build-essential. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: those files are part of the *source code* of `glibc`, why do you wanna debug that?

Comment: You should consider that `fscanf` is correctly behaving, according to its specification (see [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html)...). So you should then use the `next` command of `gdb`. However, you should use the result of `fscanf`. The bugs are in your code (which you don't show).

Comment: Why the tag *compiler-construction* ? It is not relevant! Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: @Amro I didn't want to debug that, when gdb hit fscanf() line, it show the error

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I tried with next command. But gdb stuck at that point showing
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
'0x0000000000400ae7 in check_word (word=0x7fffffffe36c "abaid") at hash.c:95
95             if (strcmp(word, root->word) == 0)
(gdb) '

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch should I post the full code? sorry, I'm new to C.

Comment: @ProvashA.Shoumma: see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So the bug is in your file `hash.c` which you don't show.

Comment: 1+ for being "*newbie to c programming*", but daring to use gdb! :-)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm sorry, I didn't know, when I ran gdb, I stepped into the load_words() function and then gdb showed those messages. I thought the problem was with the function.

Answer (score 3):

Your `check_word` function contains an obvious infinite cycle

```
    root = table[hash];

    while(root != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(word, root->word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

If the hash bucked is not empty and the very first entry does not match, it will loop forever, since you never advance the `root` pointer along the collision chain.

Another major problem with your code is that in `load_words` function you store a pointer to the same local `word` array in all of your hash entries. I.e. all `node` objects point to the same local array with their `word` pointers. This does not make sense and has no chance to work properly. And when `load_words` function exits, the local `word` array gets destroyed and all your `word` pointers in all hash nodes become invalid.

Each hash node has to own its own `word` memory. How you are going to achieve that is up to you. Either declare `word` inside `node` as an array, not a pointer, and then `strcpy` the local `word` into the node's `word`. Or use `strdup` when storing each word in the hash node.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the code is working, but I'm having a logical problem. The hash table is not working as expected. But I will figure that out. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the logical mistake answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your other problem comes from this line since "word" is a local variable on the stack

```
table[hash]->word = word;
```

you need to allocate storage for 'word' e.g.

```
table[hash]->word = strdup(word);
```